# How to attachment multiple file in infopath form 2010?

Tags: infopath

I want to attach multiple file in my infopath form. I already put attachment control in my infopath form. my problem is when I click the attachment file it can't open and appear.

Please help me on how to attach multiple file in infopath form 2010?

Answer (score 2):

As the duplicate only suggest what can be done, following is more helpful:

> To create a multi file attachment control in InfoPath, you can make
>   use of a [Repeating
>   Table](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/use-repeating-tables-infopath.htm)
>   that has a File Attachment as one of its fields.
>
> Perform the following steps to create a multi-file attachment in
>   InfoPath:
>
> 1. Add a **Repeating Table** with 1 column to your InfoPath form template.
> 2. Go to the **Data Source** task pane and double-click the field under the repeating node for the **Repeating Table**.
> 3. Change the **Data type** to **Picture or File Attachment (base 64)** and click **OK**.
> 4. Right-click the field in the **Repeating Table** on the InfoPath form template, and select **Change To**, and then **File Attachment**
>      from the context menu that appears.
>
> That is how you can attach multiple files in InfoPath.

Source:

[Top 10 questions about InfoPath attachments](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/04/top-10-questions-infopath-file-attachments/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution Asalan, but I already create what you sugest, but after i publish the infopath and click attachment. it can't appear